# how does Magus' Force Fang conflux spell interact with reload ranged weapons?

Tags: spells, pathfinder-2e

[Force Fang](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1038) doesn't specify that you need to actually Strike with the weapon to use the spell. It just auto-damages in varying ranges.

Does Force Fang unload a loaded ranged reload weapon? Also, would Force Fang still be valid if you use an unloaded ranged reload weapon?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## RAW You don't need a loaded weapon/lose ammo

[Reload](https://2e.aonprd.com/Rules.aspx?ID=228#:%7E:text=Reloading%20a%20ranged%20weapon%20and,spend%20to%20reload%20a%20weapon.) is a weapon statistic, [Force fang](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=1038) specifically disables all weapon statistics.

> For an instant, you transform your weapon or unarmed attack into a spike of pure force, **replacing all its normal statistics** and abilities.

Answer (score 4):

## It doesn't interact at all

This is a spell that does *not* want to give you extra range. So it's range matches your reach or the first range increment of your weapon.

The ammunition type, or the complete lack thereof doesn't matter:

> you **transform** your weapon or unarmed attack into a spike of pure force, **replacing** all its normal statistics and abilities